# boto3 not returning elements in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am using `boto3` in Python. I am getting an empty list from AWS Fraud Detector, despite having two detectors already in the console. How can I fix the code to return the two detectors listed in the console?

Console:
[image]

Code:

```
import boto3
fraudDetector = boto3.client('frauddetector',aws_access_key_id='key from the console user',
    aws_secret_access_key='key from the console user')
            
response = fraudDetector.get_detectors()
print(response)
```

Output:

```
{'detectors': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '7ee05de5-6e73-4fe1-a73f-e36a9a4e5c42', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'date': 'Wed, 19 Aug 2020 23:35:07 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '7ee05de5-6e73-4fe1-a73f-e36a9a4e5c42', 'content-length': '16', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I am guessing that this is due to some IAM / permission issue. I did verify that the credentials match on console vs code. The account is also a root user though.

Comment: What about region? Maybe you search in different region than used in console?

Comment: It works!!! you saved me!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that boto3 was searching detectors in **different region** that the region used in console.

The **solution** was to setup the proper region for boto3.